# SQLite view Database button not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've moved working database code from an old project and have the `createEntry` function working. However, when I click on my button to show the db, the app crashes. I checked the LogCat and found this, among other errors that seem to be because of this:

```
12-09 12:51:58.992: E/AndroidRuntime(15714):android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
No Activity found to handle Intent { act= SQLView }
```

and when I went to the corresponding code in the project found this:

```
case R.id.bSQLopenView:
 Intent i = new Intent("SQLView");
 startActivity(i);
```

I don't know why this is crashing but if anyone knows and could tell me why that would be great.

*EDIT*:

2nd error: after add to manifest:

```
12-09 13:09:54.311: E/AndroidRuntime(16665): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity    
ComponentInfo{sample.ble.sensortag/sample.ble.sensortag.SQLView}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "sample.ble.sensortag.SQLView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sample.ble.sensortag-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/sample.ble.sensortag-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

SQLView:

```
public class SQLView extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you declared your activity in Manifest file?

Comment: ahhh, god I feel stupid now. Totally forgot. Thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome..check my answer also..:-)

Comment: Actually, now I have this error: in question

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the code which opens the database and displays it when a view button is clicked. Then again I could be wrong because I haven't used this code in ages. Code now in Q.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare as :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourMainActivity.this, SQLView.class);
```

SQLView.class is a java file and you have to declare this in your manifest file.

Hope this helps.